# Amount calculation in textfield cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a scenario where after selecting a particular product the amount is reflected in a textfield and when we click on a checkbox the amount doubles automatically.
This is my code:

```
cy.getBySel('textfield').click().then(($title) => {
         const op1 = $title.val().replace('$', " ").trim()
            cy.log(op1) -- Here i get the amount without the currency ;  an amount example can be 25,15
            const totalProduct = op1 * 2  , 
            cy.log(totalProduct) //when i print here i get NaN
            cy.get('#product-checkbox').click()
            cy.getBySel('textfield').click().should('have.value', totalProduct) 
    // Here i need to check the value is equal to op1*2 that is totalProduct
    
When I am running the test, I am getting: 
expected <input> to have value NaN, but the value was 50,30 $
```

Can someone please advise why I am getting NaN even if I am trimming the currency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All values taken from the page are text.

To do math on it, convert to a number first.

```js
const op1 = $title.val().replace('$', " ").trim()
const totalProduct = +(op1.replace(',', '.')) * 2   
cy.get('#product-checkbox').click()
cy.getBySel('textfield').click()
  .should('have.value', totalProduct.toLocaleString('de-DE'))
```

The final line comparing text values above is using two strings, but it might be more precise to compare numbers instead.

```js
const op1 = $title.val().replace('$', " ").trim()
const totalProduct = +(op1.replace(',', '.')) * 2   
cy.get('#product-checkbox').click()
cy.getBySel('textfield').click()
  .should($title2 => {
    const op2 = $title2.val().replace('$', " ").trim()
    expect(op2).to.eq(totalProduct)                  // compare numbers
  })
```

You can go one more step, make a function of the conversion

```js
const toNumber = ($el) => {
  return +($el.val().replace('$', " ").trim().replace(',', '.'))
}

const totalProduct = toNumber($title) * 2   
cy.get('#product-checkbox').click()
cy.getBySel('textfield').click()
  .should($title2 => {
    const op2 = toNumber($title2)
    expect(op2).to.eq(totalProduct)          // compare numbers
  })
```

Comment: I am still getting NaN :(

Comment: You could try `parseInt(op1) * 2`, but the problem may be with the text itself. Can you `console.log(op1)` please.

Comment: When i do console.log(op1) i get 25,15

Comment: I see in the comment the text is `25,15` - if this is a European decimal, try `parseInt(op1.replace(',', '.')) * 2`.

Comment: i am getting:

expected <input> to have value '50', but the value was 50,30 $ ..I need the amount with the decimal place as well as its a round up amount

Comment: Also if i am not getting the $ in the expected amount will it throw error. Maybe i should use include instead of have.value

Comment: Ok, my mistake - parseInt will take off the `.15`. Try `+op1.replace(',', '.') * 2` or `parseFloat(op1.replace(',', '.')) * 2`

Comment: If there's no `$` in the string `$title.val().replace('$', " ").trim()` will not error, it will just do nothing (expect trim).

Comment: I am getting the amount in . how to get it with ,

Comment: That should be `.toLocaleString('de-DE')`

Comment: But I wonder if it should compare numerically. I will add that also.

Comment: I just added a missing bracket above (2nd line)

Comment: For your second answer i am getting:
expected 50,30 $ to equal NaN

Comment: For the 3rd one i am getting expected NaN to be NaN

Comment: I just tried it out and it worked ok, so I don't know what else to add, sorry.

Comment: It was an error on my side. All good.Thanks for your help